# In the USA, is it illegal for a group of people to agree to purchase or sell a particular stock?

Tags: united-states, stocks, law, security, regulation

I am researching this as a part of a story plot involving hundreds to thousands of people who are members of a religious organization and who have agreed to buy and sell a particular company's shares in an attempt to create upward / downward momentum and to profit from the changes.

In the USA, are there laws that would make this illegal? If so, what laws are they?

Comment: Pretty sure all you'd manage to do is shuffle money back and forth, at least til it all gets eaten up in SEC fees and such. (In order to play this game, you'd need a stock where your purchases and sales could have a noticeable impact, which would be a stock where existing demand is relatively low.)

Comment: In a pump and dump scheme, the perps take their positions in small float stocks and then push price up with false or exaggerated statements in cold calls.  As the buying ebbs, the schemers dump their shares at higher prices, leaving a lot of bag holders in their wake. The difference between P&D and the OP's scenario is that the P&D involves other (gullible) buyers.  A "religious group" buying and selling the stock would effectively amount to shuffling money around because late buyers from the group would rack up losses as the early buyers sold and share price dropped.

Comment: @BobBaerker, OP did not say how that organization would execute their scheme. Maybe it's intended to be some scaled up version of the scenario in this other question: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90179/what-prevents-stock-prices-from-being-artificially-increased

Comment: The OP did not say how that organization would execute their scheme because he's in the process of writing a story, probably fiction but based on the reality of the market - hence the question he posed.  I'm not going to speculate on what he intended or whether it links to another question posed on SE.  All I can do is explain how the market works and why that makes his premise  flawed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is prohibited by the [Securities Exchange Act of 1934](https://www.sec.gov/about/laws/sea34.pdf), Section 9(a)(2).

> SEC.  9.  (a)  It  shall  be  unlawful  for  any  person,  directly  or  indirectly,  by  the  use  of  the  mails  or  any  means  or  instrumentality  of  interstate commerce, or of any facility of any national securities exchange, or for any member of a national securities exchange—
>
> (2)  To  effect,  alone  or  with  1  or  more  other  persons,  a  series of  transactions  in  any  security  other  than  a  government  security, any  security  not  so  registered,  or  in  connection  with  any  security-based  swap  or  security-based  swap  agreement  with  respect  to  such security creating actual or apparent active trading in such security, or  raising  or  depressing  the  price  of  such  security,  for  the  purpose of inducing the purchase or sale of such security by others.

Comment: Isn't this essentially what pump-and-dump scammers try and do with penny stocks by hyping them in newsletters, advertisements, spam, etc?

Comment: Yes, and pump-and-dumping stocks is illegal.  Hard to prove intent and prosecute, but still illegal.

Comment: Or in other words, it's not illegal to trade in a group, but it is illegal to try to manipulate prices?

Comment: Hmm, the *only reason* to trade in a group is to (try to) manipulate prices.  State, any other reason to trade in a group.  Like - for dating reasons?  The feelgood factor?  The *only* reason to trade in a group is to (try to) manipulate prices.

Comment: @Fattie. what if the groups "reason" for trading together is simply to make money (for themselves or for someone else)? I mean if their purchases or sales of a stock has an **effect** on the price, where does it become "manipulation". I mean this because everyone else's purchases or sales have an effect on it as well (although it is minuscule unless the individual investor is able to buy huge amounts). Other than that perhaps their reason for buying or selling could be something like "to support causes they care about"(?)

Comment: it's a reasonable point that another reason could be "support causes" (good one for thinking about that).  but the overwhelming answer to the QA at hand is just "yeah that's manipulation".  the whole "market-government complex" is set up and operated a certain way to have certain winners (guess who).  they have far more guns than any other party, so that's the end of it.

Comment: It's not about who has more guns. In fact, you probably wouldn't even get in trouble for "manipulation" unless you were trying to convince people outside the cult to buy. And if you don't do that, there's basically no net gain for the cult -- just for the people who realize buying high and selling low is just giving money away, and thus refuse to do it.

Comment: @Fattie I know that there exist chatrooms with groups of people who watch various cryptocurency prices and "sound the alarm" when one moves violently in one direction or another. In this sense its not so much "trading in a group", and they likely have very little impact on the price since it is more reactionary than anything, but this does often result in the group members trading in a similar manner to each other

Comment: Cryptocurrencies are (in the US, at least) not regulated by the SEC.  As long as you avoid outright fraud, market manipulation of them is entirely (again, in the US) legal.